# Golint plugin for Sublime Text 3

Tags: go, sublimetext3, sublimelinter, golint

i'm currently learning Go, and i'm using `Sublime Text 3` with the `SublimeLinter` plugin (which i use with other languages besides Go). I've downloaded Go using `Homebrew` (i'm on OS X), and i've followed the procedure explained here: https://golang.org/doc/install for testing my installation. I can't figure out why the linter for the Go language provided by `SublimeLinter` don't work. I've inserted my `$GOPATH` in my `PATH`, and `/usr/local/bin/go` too.
Here is what prints the ST's console:

```
SublimeLinter: golint activated: /Users/gianmarco/Documents/Dev/Go/bin/golint 
Emmet: No need to update PyV8
SublimeLinter: chdir not set or invalid, using /Users/gianmarco/Documents/Dev/Go/src/github.com/gianmarco/hello 
SublimeLinter: golint: hello.go guessed GOPATH=/Users/gianmarco/Documents/Dev/Go 
SublimeLinter: golint: hello.go ['/Users/gianmarco/Documents/Dev/Go/bin/golint'] 
Package Control: Skipping automatic upgrade, last run at 2015-11-28 11:58:34, next run at 2015-11-28 12:58:34 or after
SublimeLinter: chdir not set or invalid, using /Users/gianmarco/Documents/Dev/Go/src/github.com/gianmarco/hello 
SublimeLinter: golint: hello.go guessed GOPATH=/Users/gianmarco/Documents/Dev/Go 
SublimeLinter: golint: hello.go ['/Users/gianmarco/Documents/Dev/Go/bin/golint'] 
SublimeLinter: chdir not set or invalid, using /Users/gianmarco/Documents/Dev/Go/src/github.com/gianmarco/hello 
SublimeLinter: golint: hello.go guessed GOPATH=/Users/gianmarco/Documents/Dev/Go 
SublimeLinter: golint: hello.go ['/Users/gianmarco/Documents/Dev/Go/bin/golint']
```

Someone has the same problem?

Comment: [GoSublime](https://github.com/DisposaBoy/GoSublime) may be a better choice.

Comment: If a won't find a solution i'll check that one, thank you!

Comment: Did you read all of the setup and configuration instructions for [`SublimeLinter-contrib-golint`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter-contrib-golint)? Just changing your `$PATH` in your `.bash_profile` or wherever doesn't change the `PATH` that Sublime (and its plugins) see.

Comment: I've followed the same procedure that i used for the others linters, i'll check for other setups then.